# how to determine exact spacing between UICollectionView cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am newbie in IOS dev . I was given job to make calendar app. I am using `UICollectionViewCell` to display days 1-30. for daynames like "S M T W TH F S" I used supplementary view(headerCell) and adding 7 `UILabels` with SPACING same as distance between two cells. I see Daynames are not aligned vertically to Day Numbers. I have extended `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to set `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex` to 2 and I managed the cell sizes to display only 7 days(1 week) per row.

I also calculated distance between 2 cells using their centres , taking that distance as reference and adding it as distance between labels in `HeaderCell`, but still they are not getting aligned.

I am looking to exactly calculate distance between cells in `UICollectionView`. the spacing we set is just minimum and it differs sometimes depending on iPhone screen size.

Here is the Pic:
[missing alignment with day cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpJLM.png)
Here is my code:

```
    extension FirstViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
            var cwidth:CGFloat = 0.0
            cwidth = (collectionView.frame.size.width/7 - PADDING - SPACING)

            let cheight = collectionView.frame.size.height/7
            cellWidth = cwidth
            cellHeight = cheight
            print("Cell width is \(cellWidth) and view width is \(collectionView.frame.size.width)")
            return CGSize(width: cwidth, height: cheight )

        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
            return UIEdgeInsets(top:1.0,left:1.0,bottom:1.0,right:1.0)
        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 1.0
        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return SPACING
        }

    }

      class FirstViewController:       
     UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate 
    {

     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,    
      viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath:    
      NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView 
    {



        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        var prevWidth:CGFloat = 5.0

        var frame1 :CGRect? = nil

        for (index,i) in daynames.enumerate() {

            if (index == 0){
            frame1 = CGRect(x: 1.0, y: -2.0, width: cellWidth  , height: cellHeight)
            }
            else{
              frame1 = CGRect(x: CGFloat(prevWidth)  , y: -2.0,width:cellWidth   , height: cellHeight)
            }
            if (index < 6){
            prevWidth = frame1!.origin.x  + cellWidth + distances[index] - SPACING
            }
            let label = UILabel(frame:frame1!)
            label.text = i
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            label.font = UIFont(name:"Helvetica",size:16)
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
           // label.center.x = cell_centres[index]
            cell.addSubview(label)

        }

        return cell

}
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath     indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let label = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        //testing purpose
        label.text = String(days[indexPath.row])

        if indexPath.row == 0{
            cell_centres.removeAll()
        }

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        if indexPath.row < 7{

            cell_centres.append(cell.center.x)

            print("appending \(cell.center.x)")
        }

        //code for calc distances between cells
        if(prevX == 0){
            prevX = cell.center.x
        }
        else if(indexPath.row < 7){
            distance = floor((cell.center.x - prevX) - cellWidth)
            print("distance \(distance) ")
            distances.append(distance)
            prevX = cell.center.x
        }
        return cell

    }
    }
```